# Open Frameworks : draw function being recalled multiple times

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I was working with Openframeworks on C++. I was trying to plot some points on graph using api of openweathermap.org. The function plotAxes() and plotGraph() is being called mutiple times. 
Could anyone suggest me?

```
void ofApp::draw()
{
 ofDrawBitmapString("Current Temperature Graph (openweathermap.org)", 600,50);
 ofDrawBitmapString ("X-axis : Temperature in Kelvin-- One division =100K",600,600);
 ofDrawBitmapString ("Y-axis : Cities-- One division =100K",600,650);
 plotAxes();
 plotGraph();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in openframeworks draw() method functions called every frame. If you want the functions plotAxes() and plotGraph() called once you can put these functions in setup() method.
example:

```
void ofApp::setup(){
 plotAxes();
 plotGraph();
}
```